# Is there any simple way to change my bar graph alignment and increase its width on LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, bar-chart, axis

So I'm pretty new to using LaTeX. I created this bar graph, but it's too wide to fit in my PDF doc. I don't want to rotate the graph. I also need this graph to be aligned to the flush left margin of my page so that I can then figure out how to change the width to make sure my text fits. Is there any way that I can also make the x-axis labels fit without decreasing the text size but by making the labels two-lined?

Not sure if my questions make sense but I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code I have so far:

```
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, 
    enlargelimits=0.10,
    width=7in,
    height=5in,
    bar width= 20pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Counts},
    symbolic x coords={Less Than HS, HS incomplete, HS graduate, Some college, Associate degree, Bachelor's, PG incomplete, PG degree},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot [color=gray, fill= lightgray] coordinates {(Less Than HS, 3) (HS incomplete, 21) (HS graduate, 211) (Some college, 127) (Associate degree, 92) (Bachelor's,162) (PG incomplete, 12) (PG degree, 96)};
\addplot [color=gray, fill= darkgray] coordinates {(Less Than HS, 35) (HS incomplete, 32) (HS graduate, 163) (Some college, 122) (Associate degree, 88) (Bachelor's,186) (PG incomplete, 17) (PG degree, 190)};

\legend{Protect,Control}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make code fragment compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please, always provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. By it you will help us to help you.
- Your `xticklabel` are to wide. To make it narrower, you have several options:

  - use smaller fonts (by defining `xticklabel style` in `axis` options)
  - rotate them for some angle
  - combined aforementioned options

A possible solution:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.10,
    width=7in,
    height=5in,
    bar width= 20pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.13)},
                  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Counts},
    symbolic x coords={Less Than HS, HS incomplete, HS graduate, 
                       Some college, Associate degree, Bachelor's, 
                       PG incomplete, PG degree},
    xticklabel style = {text width=4em, align=flush right, inner sep=1pt,
                        rotate=30, anchor=north east,
                        font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},    % <---
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot [color=gray, fill= lightgray] coordinates {(Less Than HS, 3) (HS incomplete, 21) (HS graduate, 211) (Some college, 127) (Associate degree, 92) (Bachelor's,162) (PG incomplete, 12) (PG degree, 96)};
\addplot [color=gray, fill= darkgray] coordinates {(Less Than HS, 35) (HS incomplete, 32) (HS graduate, 163) (Some college, 122) (Associate degree, 88) (Bachelor's,186) (PG incomplete, 17) (PG degree, 190)};

\legend{Protect,Control}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked beautifully!

Comment: @AkiVivek, you are welcome. BTW, you may consider to accept answer (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer)